# FFmpeg stops Process C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I believe my "FFmpeg" process is getting stuck in a infinite loop or it's waiting for something and I don't know what that is. It won't pass the `WaitForExit` method.

FFmpeg:

```
-ss 0 -i output.mp4 -t 10 -an -y test.mp4
```

C# Code:

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName; // ffmpeg.exe
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments; //-ss 0 -i output.mp4 -t 10 -an -y test.mp4
     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit(); // stops here and waits

     return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

**Edit:**

Adding `-loglevel quiet` to my `ffmpeg` query made my problem disappear. Why? How can I achieve same results with out adding `-loglevel quiet`?

Comment: Have you tried to call "ffmpeg.exe" in the terminal with this arguments to see if the executable really exits?

Comment: @Leonardo Menezes Did. Works fine in `cmd`, but when I use it in `Process` it stops and waits.

Comment: Try setting the filename to your powershell, like: "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" and setting the arguments to "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "ffmpeg.exe -ss 0 -i output.mp4 -t 10 -an -y test.mp4" " to see how it behaves.

Comment: @Leonardo Menezes Got: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll Additional information: Access is denied`

Comment: Okay, now we got two options: your c# code doesn't have access to powershell or your  powershell  doesn`t have access to ffmpeg.exe. Maybe this problem is related to your original problem, that error might be the cause for your never-ending process. I suggest  some debugging,  trying to give administrator priveleges to your visual  studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are redirecting standard and error outputs, but then you don't read from them until child process exits.

There is a buffer of limited size associated with those outputs, and when this buffer becomes full - process (in this case ffmpeg) blocks when trying to write there. So this buffer is like queue: one side (one process, ffmpeg) pushes stuff there, and another side (your process, because you redirected output) is expected to pop them from queue. If you do not do that - queue becomes full and one process cannot push items there, so it blocks waiting for space to become available.

For that reason adding `-loglevel quiet` "solves" the problem, reducing output of ffmpeg so that it fits into buffer even without you ever reading from it.

So easiest solution is - don't redirect error output (you are not reading it anyway), and read standard output:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;                
process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName; // ffmpeg.exe
process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments; //-ss 0 -i output.mp4 -t 10 -an -y test.mp4
process.Start();
string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit(); // stops here and waits
return result;
```

If you need to read from both error and standard output, or if you need a timeout - that's more complicated, but you can find plenty of solutions on internet.

Comment: There should be something about emptying out the buffer after every command call in the documentation tooltip. This fixed a weird bug in my app when it would just stop working.